# css - overflow: hidden in div nested inside display: table-cell

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-tables

I've got a problem with overflow in a div nested inside another div which has display: table-cell style. I'm not sure why content from #left-wrapper is not cropped (hidden) when it exceeds height of #left-wrapper. Thanks in advance for any advices. Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/bpbHY/1/

Here's my markup:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">
        <div id="left-wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li>Menu item</li>
                <li>Menu item</li>
                <li>Menu item</li>
                <li>Menu item</li>
                <li>Menu item</li>
                <li>Menu item</li>
                <li>Menu item</li>
                <li>Menu item</li>
                <li>Menu item</li>
                <li>Menu item</li>
                <li>Menu item</li>
                <li>Menu item</li>
                <li>Menu item</li>
                <li>Menu item</li>
                <li>Menu item</li>
                <li>Menu item</li>
                <li>Menu item</li>
                <li>Menu item</li>
                <li>Menu item</li>
                <li>Menu item </li>
            <ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="center">Center content</div>
    <div id="right">right</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper > div {
    display:table-cell;
    height:100%;
}
#left {
    width:70px;
    min-width:80px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:pink;
}

#left-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

#center {
    background-color:green;
    min-width:200px;
}
#right {
    width:50px;
    min-width:50px;
    background-color:red;
}
li {
    line-height: 80px;
}
body, html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Does that work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/bpbHY/2/

Comment: I don't see any problem... If i change the `#left-wrapper`'s hight, it get's croped...

Comment: your explanation is not clear.

Comment: I'd like to make content of #left scrollable (using IScroll), so I need to crop/hide just the content of #left-wrapper.

Comment: @Mr_Green: I'd like to have 'fluid' height for whole #wrapper (100% of possible height) but if content of #left-wrapper is longer, then I'd like to hide it (it'll be a scrollable area)

Comment: Do you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/bpbHY/4/

Comment: @Barnee: I don't want to specify the height of `#left-wrapper`, I just want to avoid effect of expanding `#wrapper` and `#left` divs. (They should always fit in the height of browser's window)

Comment: @Mr_Green: Ok, I didn't notice the overflow: auto. However, in Firefox it's not wokring, In Chrome does but for IScroll (js library) purposes I need to make it with overflow: hidden.

Comment: @krlm So, you mean you want to hide the scroller but still the content should scroll.. right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35338/discussion-between-krlm-and-mr-green)

Comment: Also, you may want to close your ul tags, you have a second opening tag instead of a closing tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `overflow: hidden` is not working because you are using `display: table` and `display: table-cell`. and also I used positioning to center the #center.

Here is the [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/bpbHY/14/)

PS: I am using `min-width: 200px` which you might want to change as your need.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I'd be happy if somebody could send me to the css reference where I could read about that issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem is occurring because of your use of display: table; and table-cell

I've taken the liberty of re-designing the CSS you have and I think this is what you're looking for:

Html stays the same and the CSS is as follows:

```
* {margin:0;padding:0;}
html, body{
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}
li {
    line-height: 80px;
}
#wrapper{
    width: 100%;
}
#left-wrapper {
    background: pink;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
#left-wrapper ul {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    background: pink;
}

#center {
    background-color:green;
    height: 100%;
    width: 70%;
    min-width:200px;
    float: left;
}
#right {
    width: 15%;
    min-width:50px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:red;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure , but maybe this will be useful for you:

```
li {
line-height: 80px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bpbHY/3/)

Comment: Not really, menu items are still expanding the height of #left-wrapper/#wrapper

Comment: I've checked in Chrome and Firefox (most current)

Comment: I misunderstood your  question, but i think you need to use javascript to set get `wrapper` height and apply it to `left-wrapper`or something like that

Answer (score 0):

After this, set listitems as `overflow: scroll;` it should work.

**http://jsfiddle.net/bpbHY/8/**

Comment: Which element should have this overflow: scroll in my case? (I'd like to avoid browser scroll, overflow: hidden will be just enough for me)